# CSS to Change Required Message?

Tags: cognito-forms

What CSS would I use to change the default pink color on the backgrounds of the validation messages if someone does not enter a required field? (shown below). I can't determine what selector that is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this blog post by Tyler, one of the great designers at [CognitoForms](https://www.cognitoforms.com):

[Styling Cognito Forms with CSS](http://blog.cognitoapps.com/styling-cognito-forms-with-css)

Also, you can inspect elements to see the classes applied to them (hint, they all start with `c-` and they are all named sensibly).  The class for error messages is `c-validation`.  You will likely need to use `!important` to override any styles explicitly applied by Cognito Forms.